# The ViewData item that has the key 'FabricanteId' is of type 'System.Int64' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação em ASP.NET MCV 5. Esse trecho está retornando essa mensagem de erro.

```
@Html.DropDownList("FabricanteId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FabricanteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Esse é o model:

```
namespace Projeto01.Models
{
    public class Fabricante
    {
        public long FabricanteId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Esse é o método de edição:

```
// GET: Produtos/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Produto produto = context.Produtos.Find(id);
        if (produto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(context.Categorias.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "CategoriaId", "Nome", produto.CategoriaId);
        ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(context.Fabricantes.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "FabricanteId", "Nome", produto.FabricanteId);
        return View(produto);
    }

// POST: Produtos/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Produto produto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(produto);

        }
        catch
        {
            return View(produto);
        }
    }

    // GET: Produtos/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta a *Action* `Edit` como `GET`?

Comment: Acrescentei o GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é um typo, aqui:

```
    ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(context.Categorias.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "CategoriaId", "Nome", produto.CategoriaId);
    ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(context.Fabricantes.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "FabricanteId", "Nome", produto.FabricanteId)
```

Deveria ser:

```
    ViewBag.CategoriaId = new SelectList(context.Categorias.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "CategoriaId", "Nome", produto.CategoriaId);
    ViewBag.FabricanteId = new SelectList(context.Fabricantes.OrderBy(b => b.Nome), "FabricanteId", "Nome", produto.FabricanteId)
```